# NoMethodError in controller#new - undefined method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm getting a `NoMethodError` in the `new` action of my `business_controller`.

It seems to be acessing the `@business` object for a form in my view and the error occurs then:

```
undefined method `businesses_path' for
```

Here is my new method:

```
def new
  if Business.where(:user_id => current_user.id).first.blank?
    @business = Business.new
  else
    redirect_to user_businesses_path(current_user.id)
  end
end
```

My routes are:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :businesses
      member do
        get 'account'
        post 'payment'
        put 'update_password'
        get 'membership'
      end
  end
```

**mind.blank's suggested changes**

`before_filter :check_if_user_has_business, :only => :index`

```
   def new
      @business = Business.new
   end

  private
  def check_if_user_has_business
    redirect_to new_user_business_path(current_user) unless current_user.business
  end
```

Comment: You should put private methods *after* your other actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a route `businesses_path` or only `user_businesses_path`? If you only have the second one then you should specify that URL in your form:

```
<%= form_for @business, url: user_businesses_path do |f| %>
```

Also, if you have the correct associations set up, then you can write your `if` statement as follows:

```
if current_user.business.nil? # since it's a has_one association
```

Here's how I would write it:

```
Class BusinessesController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_if_user_has_business, only: :new

  def new
    @business = Business.new
  end

  private

  def check_if_user_has_business
    redirect_to user_businesses_path(current_user) if current_user.business
  end
end
```

Comment: That fixed it thank you. What is the benefit to changing the if statement> Just readability?

Comment: Associations make your life easier, rather than passing around user IDs all the time you can just do `user.businesses`, `user.businesses.first`, `user.business.where("revenue > ?", 30000)` etc.

Comment: I tried your change but I now get the error: undefined method `businesses'. I assume because my business model has a reference to user_id but my user has no ref to a business.

Comment: No problem, I've update my answer with a cleaner way to write the controller.

Comment: if check_if_user_has_business is NO it doesn't seem to be calling new

Comment: Hmm, it should work. Try changing it to `unless current_user.business.nil?`

Comment: Nope. My text editor is showing a possible syntax error on this line:   before_filter :check_if_user_has_business, only: :new and I'm getting undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Unexpected ':', expecting kEND; Warning unused literal ignored.

Comment: Perhaps you're using an older version of Ruby, try `:only => :new` instead of `only: :new`

Comment: Got it working, I'll add the correct implementation to my question. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I meant to be calling it on my index and redirecting to /new if no business existed. Updated code in the question.

Comment: Oh I see, make sure you put your `private` methods after your other actions.